# Counting and comparing strings from scv file

Tags: java, csv

I have a big csv file of 18000 rows. They represent different kinds of articles from a liqueur store. If I with bufferedReader split up the rows I get columns with stuff like - article number, name, amount of alcohol, price etc etc.

In the seventh column is the type of beverage (beer, whine rum etc.). What would be the best way to count how many articles there are of each type? I would like to be able to do this without having to know the types. And I only want to use java.util.*.

Can I read through the column and store it in a queue. While reading I store each new type in a set. Then I can maybe compare all elements in the queue to this set?

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // using \t as separator
                String[] articles = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
```

The output should be something like.

```
There are: 
100 beers
2000 whines 
etc. etc.

in the sortiment
```

Comment: Have you tried using a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)?

Comment: I actually just started reading about it. I'm very new to java. But it seems like HashMap would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `HashMap<String, integer>` in order to know how many products of each category you have. The usage would be like:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> productCount = new HashMap<>(); //This must be outsise the loop

//read you CSV here, this should be placed inside the loop
String product = csvColumns[6];
if(productCount.containsKey(product)) { //If the product doesn't exist
    productCount.put(product, 1);
} else { //Product exists, add 1
    int count = productCount.get(product);
    productCount.put(productCount, count+1);
}
```

***DISCLAIMER*** You have to be sure all products are named the same ie: `beer` or `Beer`. To Java, these are different Strings, and so, will have different count. One way will be to conver every product to uppercase ie: `beer` -> `BEER` `Beer`->`BEER`. This will cause to show all names in uppercase when showing results.